# Website stopped working - bad flag delimiters error

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've had a website that has worked for a year. I changed the domain name, and the hosting company copied all of the data to the new hosting account. The website worked for a few days. Now, with no changes made, I've got a `500 Internal Server Error`.

The error log says:

> /home/website/public_html/.htaccess: RewriteRule: bad flag delimiters

The `.htaccess` file in the `public_html` folder says:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?website.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/cmsfolder/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /cmsfolder/$1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?website.com$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ cmsfolder/index.php [L]Options +Indexes
Options +Indexes
IndexOptions -FancyIndexing
```

I haven't changed anything, so I am not sure why the website would just switch to a 500 server error.

To be honest, I have no idea what I am doing with it and the hosting company does not seem to know either.

Comment: Is that actually what the file looks like (with the exception of all the `<br>` that you added in)? Because one of the `RewriteRule` lines is very obviously wrong.

Comment: Yes. Which line is wrong? This is something the hosting company did the other day, although, it has been working since they did it.

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> RewriteRule ^(/)?$ cmsfolder/index.php [L]Options +Indexes
> ```

This would result in the "RewriteRule: bad flag delimiters" error because `[L]Options` is not a valid *flags* argument. This is two directives joined together. `Options +Indexes` is an entirely separate directive, which you already have on the next line, so it should simply be deleted:

```
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ cmsfolder/index.php [L]
```

> This is something the hosting company did the other day, although, it has been working since they did it.

Exactly as written, this would have broken immediately - so something must have changed.

If the file has not been explicitly edited then my *guess* is that the `.htaccess` file has been re-uploaded and line-endings have been incorrectly converted by the FTP software (maybe there was a mix of different line-endings when the file was edited)?

---

Just FYI (in case this was how the directive was written initially), the following (with a *space* between `[L]` and `Options`) would *not* have resulted in such an error:

```
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ cmsfolder/index.php [L] Options +Indexes
```

Because *spaces* are delimiters in Apache config files and everything after the last argument, ie. `[L]` is simply ignored.